# Vectorizing standard deviation calculations for pandas dataseries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, standard-deviation

I have a pandas Series, like so,

```
data = [1,2,3,2,4,5,6,3,5]
ds = pd.Series(data)
print (ds)

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    2
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    3
8    5
```

I am interested in getting the standard deviation for each index. For example, when I at index 5, I want to calculate the standard deviations for `ds[0:4]`.

I have done this with the following code,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['data', 'avreturns', 'sd'])
df.data = data        

for i in df.index:
    dataslice = df.ix[0:i]
    df['avreturns'].loc[i] = dataslice.data.mean()
    df['sd'].loc[i] = dataslice.data.std()
print (df)

   data avreturns         sd
0     1         1        NaN
1     2       1.5  0.7071068
2     3         2          1
3     2         2  0.8164966
4     4       2.4   1.140175
5     5  2.833333    1.47196
6     6  3.285714   1.799471
7     3      3.25   1.669046
8     5  3.444444   1.666667
```

This works, but I using a loop and it is slow. Is there a way to vectorize this?

I was able to vectorize the mean calculations by using the `cumsum()` function:

```
df.data.cumsum()/(df.index+1)
```

Is there a way to vectorize the standard deviation calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in `pd.expanding_std`, which calculates the cumulative standard deviation for you:

```
>>> pd.expanding_std(ds)
0         NaN
1    0.707107
2    1.000000
3    0.816497
4    1.140175
5    1.471960
6    1.799471
7    1.669046
8    1.666667
dtype: float64
```

For what it's worth, this type of cumulative operation might be very fiddly to vectorise: [the Pandas implementation](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/stats/moments.py) appears to loop using Cython for speed.

Comment: Thanks.. this is what I am looking for. I did a performance comparison between the two ways... there is 1000x improvement in performance.

Comment: No problem. There are several of these "expanding" functions (mean, variance, max, etc.) which often come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

To expand @ajcr's answer, I ran a %timeit against the two ways to do this. I think there is 1000x improvement by using expanding_stds...

```
data = [x for x in range(1000)]
ds = pd.Series(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['data', 'avreturns', 'sd'])
df.data = data        

def foo(df):
    for i in df.index:
        dataslice = df.ix[0:i]
        df['avreturns'].loc[i] = dataslice.data.mean()
        df['sd'].loc[i] = dataslice.data.std()
    return (df)

%timeit foo(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 1min 36s per loop

%timeit pd.expanding_std(df.data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 µs per loop
```